# Cannot find any documentation on OMS log searching with dates

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I want to search my OMS logs for a specific date range

When I do:

`search *`

I see there are fields like `Timestamp_t` which are dates.

I wish to search for specific dates or ranges of dates. However I have tried every conceivable syntax I could find and try to obtain from documentation on google, and nothing has worked.

Thousands of variations of this kind of thing:

`search * | where Timestamp_t > 2018-01-02`

Could anybody advise me how to search between say, january 2nd at 3pm and january 4th at 11am? And if there is a super obvious guide to the syntax I can use somewhere? I tried this one but it didn't explain anything well enough to try https://www.stefanroth.net/2017/03/09/oms-log-search-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

`Heartbeat 
| where TimeGenerated > datetime(2018-01-15)`

Reference: https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Language-Reference/Data-types/datetime